# How can i parse this json using php?

Tags: php, json

Here is my json string:

```
{
   "id": "100007460521803_1498098053782198"
}
```

I want to display the id.. im using this code unsuccessfully:

```
$json = file_get_contents('id.txt');
$decode = json_decode($json);
echo $decode->id;
```

Error:

**Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/xtremepi/public_html/who-viewed/test.php on line 6**

any ideas?

Comment: Does your code produce any error?

Comment: what means 'unsuccessfully'? what is the output? where is the error thrown? works fine for me

Comment: Your code looks fine and isn't reproducible. Seems as though `file_get_contents()` doesn't get your JSON string.

Comment: I feel your code is right and it should work without any problem

Comment: The code is correct http://codepad.viper-7.com/EEZ8jf

Comment: Try var_dump($decode) to see what you're getting from the json_decode(). Post results

Comment: have you enabled error display? otherwise you need to dig for errors in the apache log (I suppose you're using apache)

Comment: Your error suggests you are attempting to use your object as an array, but your code shows no evidence of that. Are you providing your code **in full**?

Comment: The error does not make any sense with the code you provided. can you post the full contents of 'test.php'?

Comment: I was about to say the same thing.  It looks like the full example of the JSON string is not visible.  `id` is likely nested further inside the JSON object so the OP would likely need to do something like `echo $decode->customer->id;`

Comment: Line 6 is unlikely `echo $decode->id;`

Answer (score -1):

I have checked and got your code is working.
You have to make sure that your `id.txt` file is in the same directory.
or
just try to replace

```
echo $decode->id;
```

by this one

```
echo $decode['id'];
```

Answer (score -2):

The error is because it apparently thinks you're treating an object (returned by json_decode()) as an array.

Try

```
echo $decode->{'id'};
```

Or failing that, use

```
$decode = json_decode($json, true);
```

to have it output as an assoc array.

Edit: Read through the comments before downvoting... This relates to the error he's receiving. I'm waiting for him to post results from another test and I will be changing the answer then.

Comment: I know, I'm following along in the comments. This is referring to the error he's receiving. I'm waiting for him to post results from the `var_dump($decode)`. Edits will be made when I get the opportunity to provide a more suitable answer.